# Professional Scrum Master I (PSM)

Tags: scrum, scrum-master

everyone.
I just gained the PMP certification, where I already learn something on agile, and now I want to get a certification specialized in agile.

I want to start with the Professional Scrum Master I (PSM). I made the free assessment from the scrum.org site and I got 60% off the right answer (i don't know, the exam has 30 questions too? how many right answers are needed to pass the exam?).

The principal question is: What I can study to pass the exam? I can use only the scrum guide or there is some useful book that i can buy?

Plus there is some APP (IOS) with scrum quiz for getting practice?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Scoring 60% on [Scrum.org's Scrum Open](https://www.scrum.org/open-assessments/scrum-open) is not yet close to bring ready to take the exam for real. Although some people say that you should be able to consistently score 100% on the practice exam, I believe that consistently scoring in the upper 90s% is more than sufficient. Fortunately, there are plenty of free resources to help.

First, I'd recommend reading [the Scrum Guide](https://scrumguides.org/). Even if your native language isn't English, a common recommendation is to understand the English-language version. Not all languages are fully up-to-date and some people have reported nuances that aren't reflected well in some of the translations. Plus, the Scrum.org exams are all in English. Although it's OK to use Google Translate on the exam, it may slow you down.

Beyond the Scrum Guide, [Scrum.org's Scrum Master Learning Path](https://www.scrum.org/pathway/scrum-master) contains links to free videos, articles, and blog posts on [the different competencies relevant to being a Scrum Master](https://www.scrum.org/professional-scrum-competencies) that are tested on the exam. They also recommend some books that you could buy, but the vast majority of the content here is free.

There are also [specific suggested readings for the PSM I exam](https://www.scrum.org/resources/suggested-reading-professional-scrum-master). Most of these are free, but there are also some books that you could buy. Some of these overlap with the items on the Scrum Master Learning Path.

As far as practice exams, I would recommend only using the exams from the source where you are planning to take the real exam. In the case of the PSM, I would only recommend the Scrum.org practice exams. They keep the practice exams up-to-date with the latest version of the Scrum Guide and their exams. Other practice exams may be of differing levels of quality and the way the author interprets the Scrum Guide may not be consistent with Scrum.org - an answer deemed to be correct on a different practice exam may be considered wrong by Scrum.org.

Comment: Ok I start to learning the pdf of Scrum guide and I bought two of the suggested book. Now exist any iOS app or book with quiz for make more practice ?

Comment: @Neptune I do not recommend anything other than the Open assessments on Scrum.org. I do not believe there is an official book or app, just the website. Anything other than the official Open exams may not align with what Scrum.org considers the correct answer to questions and may lead you down the wrong path.

Comment: Ok but in the open assessment there is only 30 question. After one or two try you memorised all the answer. Next how can you continue to get practice ?

Comment: @Neptune If you've completed the Learning Path and can take the relevant Open exams and get in the upper 90s-100% every time (maybe take it once or twice a day, every day for a week), you're probably ready for the PSM I and don't need further practice. The other exams tend to require experience since there are more situational questions, but the PSM I is more focused on the facts of Scrum from the Scrum Guide. The Learning Path will help get you to the why behind the facts and to be able to connect ideas. If you think that you need more, perhaps consider a training course.